# New method of LAN

Tags: dota-2

Does somebody know how start a LAN offline match in dota2 after the last updates? 
Because old methods don't work, I get some reason code problems ( 5005,5003), and other computers can't connect to game.

Comment: See this, it may help you https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338299/its-there-anyway-to-set-up-a-lan-game-on-dota-2

Comment: No, it don't work any more.